# List of products price comparison (with while loop)

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I've been writing the code, which have to check if the product from input is in list and if it is true - add it to total cost

But there is a problem which i stuck on really hard
When i make first input - all code is working properly, but when i try to input another products - they just take the price of first inputed one, so it often looks like this:

```
#first input
Spirulini
#result = Spirulini costs 31 usd
#         Total cost is 31 usd
#second input
Sause
#result = Sause costs 31 usd
#         Total cost is 62 usd
```

I think that is happening somehow because of while cycle, so would be glad if someone could help me with that issue. Also i would love to hear any feedback about how i can simplify this code, as soon as i am beginner in Python

The whole code:

```
productlist = ['Shaurma','Spirulini','Sause','Cabbage']
pricelist = [56,31,4,9]
totalcost = 0

inpt = input()
indx = productlist.index(inpt)
price = pricelist[indx]
endWord = 'stop'

while inpt.lower() != endWord.lower():

  if inpt in productlist:
    totalcost += price
    print("\n{} costs {:d} usd".format(inpt, price))
    print (f'Total cost is {totalcost}')
    inpt = input()

  elif inpt not in productlist:
    print("Product is not found, try again")
    inpt = input()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `indx` and `price` at each iteration of the while loop. The product to look up changes on every iteration of the `while` loop, but since you store the prices of the corresponding product in separate variables, those need to be updated as well:

```py
while inpt.lower() != endWord.lower():

  if inpt in productlist:
    indx = productlist.index(inpt)
    price = pricelist[indx]
    totalcost += price
    print("\n{} costs {:d} usd".format(inpt, price))
    print (f'Total cost is {totalcost}')
    inpt = input()

  elif inpt not in productlist:
    print("Product is not found, try again")
    inpt = input()
```